# How to save data stored in Application Class

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have my app data centralized in the Application Class. A singleton class that all Activities refer to when they need data (The data are already up in memory and saved in an ArrayList in Application class). The problem is that when my app goes in Background the Application is destroyed and all the data are lost, If the data were in an Activity I could override `onPause()` and save the data there in sharedPreferences but now the data are currently in Application, which as I understand doesn't allow me to override an `onPause()` callback method. So what can I do ?

Comment: Can you handle your application call ?

Comment: You can have your application class hold on to the "hot" copy of the data and automatically persist it to storage every time it is updated. This is not unlike how [`SharedPreferences.apply()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L359) works.

Comment: `(The data are already up in memory and saved in an ArrayList in Application calls)` ...Can you get the ArrayList ?

Comment: @RanjitPati You mean get it from the Active Activity? then yes

Comment: @Barend Actually the data are initialized at the beginning of the app and stay there unupdated, I need to pesist them to storage only when application in Destroyed by the OS

Comment: @libathos you can override onPause() method; please edit your question by adding more info and/or a better indentation, because it is not clear: what you want, what you have done and what is the problem.

Comment: @JaAd I cannot override onPause in the Application Class. It's not about the code. I want to save the data in Application class (which doesn't override onPause). If it was for an Activity Class that would be trivial.

Comment: Without judging the design in the question, make a "base activity" for all your activities which override onPause which in turn notifies/calls save method on Application to store data

Comment: ok that is helpful. I couldn't serialize the data and transfer them via intents through Activities, Because the are their size is too big and the intent wouldn't be transferred, that's why I used this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method saveData() in your singleton and then call it in the activity onPause().

Activity class dont have methods such onDestroy() and onPause().